# Select selected option from dynamic created html select

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, json.net

I am using a button click using  jquery to create dynamically  `<li>` that has inside html select. The value of the selects comes dynamically with json. my ul id is ulOption1

```
var strtable = '<li>';

strtable += '<select style="display: inline;width:500px"  class=" ddlOption1 form-control "  >';

$.each(res, function (i, o) {
    strtable += '<option value="'+ o.ValueName +'">'+ o.ValueName +'</option>';

});
strtable +='</select>';
strtable += '</li>';
$('#ulOption1').append($(strtable));
```

Untill now everything works great.
After the user has created as many select that he wants i would like to grap the values that has been selected. What i am trying is :

```
$('#ulOption1 li').each(function () {
    var $input = $(this).find('input');
    var grapedvalue = $(".ddlOption1 form-control option:selected").val();
});
```

but grapedvalue never takes the selected

```
ddlOption1.val();
```

Comment: $(".ddlOption1 option:selected") use this only and check

Comment: Thank you but this is giving me always the first selected value of the dropdown. If the user has add 3 dropdowns i am always taking the value of the first on the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

```
$('#ulOption1 li').each(function () {
    var $input = $(this).find('input');

    //here it will find the select in li and grab its selected value
    var grapedvalue = $(this).find(".ddlOption1 option:selected").val();

    alert(grapedvalue)
 });
```

Working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/H6rQ6/16960/

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 var selectedValue = [];
 $(".ddlOption1").each(function(){
         selectedValue.push($(this).find('option:selected').val());
    });
```

You have all the selected value of the select with attribute class `ddlOption1` in selectedValue.